# How to downgrade gcc from 4.4.4 to 4.2.1?

Tags: gcc, downgrade

The newest Ubuntu (10.10) has gcc version 4.4.4, but I need 4.2.1 for compilation issues. The library that I'm using requires me to use 4.2.1.

How can I downgrade the gcc to a specific version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really downgrade gcc.  However, if you don't need 4.2.1 specifically, but 4.2.x, you can install Ubuntu 8.04 which will continue to have the `gcc-4.2` packages supported for another 2 years.

Comment: Once installed, you can usually build your library by specifying the environment variable "CC" as "CC=gcc-4.2 .../build/command"