# How do I install and use python 2.6?

Tags: apt, python, 8.04

I use ubuntu 8.04 as I have to use [gcc 4.2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32720/how-to-downgrade-gcc-from-4-4-4-to-4-2-1). I tried to download python 2.6 using apt-get, but the package is not available.

Is there any way to use python 2.6 in ubuntu 8.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that you will be building Python 2.6 from source one way or another. I found a guide located at http://www.lysium.de/blog/index.php?/archives/229-Installing-Python-2.6-on-Ubuntu-8.04.html which seems as though it would benefit you.

Answer (score 0):

8.04 is a pretty old distribution.  It might not run python 2.6 efficiently.  Python 2.6 is standard in 10.04, you could upgrade directly from the 8.04 LTS to the 10.04 LTS.

Comment: Do I still keep the gcc 4.2 even when I upgrade to 10.04 LTS? I use 8.04 as I have to use gcc 4.2.

Comment: Unfortunately, gcc is version 4.4 at the minimum version number on Lucid.  There's no backports of Python 2.6 for 8.04, so you'd be stuck compiling python 2.6 from source if you want it on 8.04.